# Reversed null hypothesis of econometric unbiasedness

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics

Assume there are two candidate models, $\hat{f}(\beta)$ and $\hat{g}(\beta,\theta)$. If the true data generating process is $f(\beta)$, then $\hat{g}(\beta,\theta)$ is unbiased but inefficient. If, on the other hand, the true DGP is $g(\beta, \theta)$, then $\hat{f}(\beta)$ is biased.

Under a classical model selection regime, the analyst begins with $\hat{f}$ and has to reject $h_0:\theta = 0$ in order to justify using $\hat{g}$. The consequence of Type I error is biased estimate of $\beta$, and the consequence of a Type II error is an inefficient model.

In a new model selection regime, the analyst begins with $\hat{g}$ and must reject $h_0:\theta\neq0$. The consequences of Type I and Type II errors are now precisely reversed.

Is there a statistical advantage to the new method? It seems somehow "safer," but is there a way to justify this statistically? In general, would you prefer risk to be on the Type I or Type II error?

Comment: In my case the two models are a spatial error model $f(\beta)= y = X\beta+\epsilon(I-\rho W)^{-1}$ and a spatial Durbin model $g(\beta,\theta)= y = \rho W y + X\beta + WX\theta + \epsilon$. The SEM is nested in the SDM (under the case that $\theta = -\rho \beta$, so I believe that @AdamO's joint test applies. I'm trying to make the argument that because the SDM is general, tests should try to reject it, not make the case for it. Is there statistical validity for this argument?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest question here is whether the class of probability models defined by $f(\beta)$, $\beta \in \Omega_{\beta}$ is nested within the prob models $g(\beta, \theta)$, $\left\{ \beta, \theta \right\} \in \Omega_\beta \times \Omega_\theta$ such as in the case of $\mbox{Exp}(\theta)$ distributions with gamma or Weibull probability models.

If that's the case, you can use maximum likelihood to test the joint hypothesis for the maximum restricted likelihood where $\Omega_\theta$ is projected into the zero set. The negative two log likelihood ratio of the restricted and full MLEs has an asymptotic $\chi^2_1$ distribution when $\theta = 0$.

Comment: +1 This actually answers another question that I had. But is this test set up to reject whether $\mathcal{L}_g>\mathcal{L}_f$? Or can the test work in either direction?

Comment: Plain vanilla NHST says you can test for $\mathcal{H}_0: X \sim g(\beta)$ vs $\mathcal{H}_1: X \sim g(\beta, \theta)$. Where $g(\beta)$ is nested in $g(\beta, \theta)$ as in the Exponential and Weibull example. I don't think a test of parsimony works here because it is not a composite hypothesis test. Your MLE under the null hypothesis can be arbitrarily close to the MLE in the alternative hypothesis (which says $\theta=0$ though we admit $\theta=0.000000001$ under $\mathcal{H}$_0). This breaks ML testing.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_a$. If you switch $H_0$ and $H_a$ then this does not necessarily mean that you will not reject $H_a$ in favor of $H_0$. This is the asymmetry in hypothesis testing.

Comment: I realize that hypothesis tests are asymmetric, but I'm wondering if there is a normative difference. Should I feel safer about type I or type II error?